# How to show result page when integrating Struts 2 with Apache Shiro

Tags: java, spring, struts2, shiro

**Using:**

- struts2 2.5.10,
- spring 4.x,
- struts2-spring-plugin 2.5.10,
- shiro 1.4.0,
- shiro-spring 1.4.0.

**`web.xml` :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:beans.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  
  <filter>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  
  <!-- shiro filter mapping has to be first -->
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
   
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
</web-app>
```

**`beanx.xml` :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        ">
    
    <bean name="loginAction" class="example.shiro.action.LoginAction" >
         
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
        <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />
        <property name="loginUrl" value="/login.jsp" />
        
        <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
            <value>
                /login.jsp = authc
                /logout = logout
                /* = authc
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="iniRealm" class="org.apache.shiro.realm.text.IniRealm">
        <property name="resourcePath" value="classpath:shiro.ini" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
        
        <property name="realm" ref="iniRealm" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor"/>
    
</beans>
```

**`struts.xml` :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd"> 

<struts>
    
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        
        <action name="list" class="loginAction" method="list">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
        </action>
        
    </package>
    
</struts>
```

**`index.jsp` :**

```
<body>
    <s:action name="list" />
</body>
```

**`login.jsp` looks like:**

```
<form name="loginform" action="" method="post">
        <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
            <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" maxlength="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="left"><input type="checkbox"
                    name="rememberMe"><font size="2">Remember Me</font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit"
                    name="submit" value="Login"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

**`LoginAction.list()` :**

```
public String list() {

        Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

        if(currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {System.out.println("user : "+currentUser.getPrincipal());
            System.out.println("You are authenticated!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Hey hacker, hands up!");
        }
        
        return "success";
    }
```

**`shiro.ini` :**

```
[users]
root=123,admin
guest=456,guest
frank=789,roleA,roleB

# role name=permission1,permission2,..,permissionN
[roles]
admin=*
roleA=lightsaber:*
roleB=winnebago:drive:eagle5
```

`index.jsp`, `login.jsp`, and `success.jsp` are placed under webapp.

What I want is : enter into `LoginAction.list()` need to be authenticated, if login success, then run `LoginAction.list()` and return `"success"` then show `success.jsp` which defined as Struts action result.

Now `LoginAction.list()` can be executed after login successful, but `success.jsp` is not displayed, browser is a blank page.

Why?

Comment: can you post the contents of `shiro.ini`?

Comment: @RomanC I added the shiro.ini at the bottom of post, please check, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason : I used `<s:action name="list" />` in index.jsp, however, the struts doc said if we want to see the result page with `<s:action>`, then we have to set its property `executeResult` to true, that is like `<s:action name="list" executeResult="true"/>`.

In my opinion, this is a little wired, this attribute should be true by default.

Comment: Better redirect to some action from welcome page instead of using `<s:action>` tag.

Comment: It is common practice to redirect to action in welcome page. The `<s:action>` tag is useful in some cases, but it can lead to some nasty errors which are hard to debug. Overall, use `<s:action>` tag only if you know what you're doing and there is no simple way to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example how you should configure [`applicationContext.xml` with Shiro](https://shiro.apache.org/spring.html#web-applications):

```
 <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
    <value>
        # some example chain definitions:
        /admin/** = authc, roles[admin]
        /** = authc
        # more URL-to-FilterChain definitions here
    </value>
 </property>
```

The urls starting with `/admin/` are protected via role `admin`, any other URL's are not protected. Struts actions and result JSP's would be displayed if they aren't in the protected zone.